# error when using cURL

Tags: php, curl

Trying to access the URL https://memphis.ulbranet.com.br/ALEPH/ using cURL in PHP, but it presents the following error:

```
bool (false) string (80) "error: 14077417: SSL routines: SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO: SSLv3      alert illegal parameter"
```

Anyone know why?

```
<?php

ini_set( 'display_errors' , true );
error_reporting( E_ALL );

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_URL , 'https://memphis.ulbranet.com.br/ALEPH/' );

curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true );
curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false );

var_dump( curl_exec( $curl ) , curl_error( $curl ) );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is a bug in CURL, an incorrectly formatted SSL setup or a version compatibility - but you can fix it by telling CURL to use SSL version 3:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I looked all over the internet and found nothing about it, really should be some bug.

Comment: No problem. Can you mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the big green tick) so that other people find it in the future? Thanks